# In react native for ios i am getting ART Lib issue

Tags: ios, react-native

When using react-native-progress, then getting ART lib issue for iOS as per below image :

[ART LIB ISSUE IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edT8i.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn’t automatically updated in iOS when doing npm install. Try removing node modules and do npm install if that doesn’t help then you have to add ART lib in XCode manually.